# change the URL title and tagline

Tags: site-url

I am using the Divi Builder and want to change the Tagline of my page. I already changed it in Seetings --> General. Nevertheless, it doesn't change on my page even though i refresh it a couple of times. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

What do you see in the Theme Customizer in Appearance -> Customize -> General Settings -> Site Identity -> TAGLINE?

Sounds like a Caching Problem. Please try the following steps:

- Clear your Browser Cache
- Clear Cache Plugin Data (W3 Total Cache, WP Super Cache, ..)
- Clear Cache from Web hoster (for example Siteground have a Clear Cache Button in CPanel)
- If you use a CDN like Siteground Purge Cache also here